# Can't use MatIcon component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have recently updated my project to Angular v6. I am trying to install Angular Material following this guide:
[Material guide for Angular](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

This is my app's module:

```ts
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   PruebaComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   ...
   MatButtonModule, 
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   MatCheckboxModule
 ],
```

This is the html of a test component:

```html
<h3>Fab Buttons</h3>
<div class="button-row">
  <button mat-fab>Basic</button>
  <button mat-fab color="primary">Primary</button>
  <button mat-fab color="accent">Accent</button>
  <button mat-fab color="warn">Warn</button>
  <button mat-fab disabled>Disabled</button>
  <button mat-fab>
    <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">favorite</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <a mat-fab routerLink=".">Link</a>
</div>
```

However, I get this error:

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `MatIconModule` in the app.module.ts in order to use in the project.

Try this -

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: []
  imports: [MatIconModule,....]
});
```

Comment: Although this is the right answer, you should instead create a standalone module that imports Material modules, **and exports them**. After that, you only have to import the said module into your other modules, instead of having to import the material modules in all of your app modules.

Comment: @trichetriche Perfect solution, i'll try to keep in mind in my next projects.

Comment: I get this and when I use the IDE to import into the module, it adds it into the Imports array of the module where it already in the same array, creating a duplicate in `@ngModule([imports:  [ MatIconModule, MatButtonModule,..., MatIconModule ],`  It's not make the sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Material with Angular 6, you should rely on `@angular/schematics`, as explained [in their blog](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4).

simply run

```
ng add @angular/material
```

And Angular Material will be installed, set up, and you will have nothing to do.

And to use material components, follow @PardeepJain's answer.

Comment: yup `ng add..` is best solution for this if you are working with ng6

Comment: When I try to run this command I get an error: 

`Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved.
Error: Collection "@angular/material" cannot be resolved.`

Comment: Maybe a proxy issue, or an installation issue. If you want to resolve it, make a [mcve], or just use the old way (this answer was informative for other users getting into your topic)